# RestKit & iOS, JSON, Rails - How to map instances of class into a Dictionary/hash to be easily selected by unique identifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, ruby, xcode, restkit

I have a basic iOS app that interfaces with a Rails app.  The idea here is to load all `channel` objects from my RESTful `/channels.json` route set up in Rails.

I want to load all of the `Channel` objects into an NSDictionary in Xcode so that they can easily be identified using the Channel object's ID generated by ActiveRecord -- something along the lines of `[dictionary objectForKey:@"1"]`

I've had no trouble loading all the `Channel` objects into an NSArray, but getting them to load into an NSDictionary is proving tough.  I've implemented RestKit's `didLoadObjectDictionary` delegate method, and have set up my JSON response as follows: https://gist.github.com/2504664

I believe I have my mapping set up incorrectly.  The mapping for the `Channel` objects is set up as follows: https://gist.github.com/2504667

When the `didLoadObjectDictionary` method is called, the objects NSDictionary contains 0 key/value pairs.

How do I go about loading all `Channel` objects into an NSDictionary so that I can easily refer to them using `objectForKey` as explained above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still fetch things out of the nsarray using a predicate:

```
[someArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id = %@", someId]];
```

It returns another NSArray (which should have one object).

Alternatively you could use restkit's coredata mappings then simply fetch the object by ID out of core data.